# How to extract data from a string representing a collection of coordinates?

Tags: string, matlab, data-cleaning, string-parsing, text-extraction

I have a long string that looks like this:

```
[(1, 1.89), (1, 3.93), (4, 8.65), (4, 9.35), (1, 2.4), (1, 2.37), (1, 2.14), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.46), (4, 9.21), (4, 9.21), (1, 1.48), (1, 2.96), (4, 10.39), (1, 2.69), (1, 1.25), (1, 2.39), (1, 3.08), (1, 2.81), (1, 2.72), (1, 1.05), (1, 4.73), (1, 1.7), (1, 4.49), (1, 2.25), (1, 2.73), (1, 3.69), (1, 3.23), (4, 7.78), (1, 2.7), (4, 7.47), (1, 2.01), (4, 7.41), (1, 2.4), (1, 1.81), (1, 2.75), (4, 8.35), (4, 7.88), (1, 2.33), (4, 9.26), (1, 2.74), (1, 1.43), (1, 3.14), (1, 4.44), (1, 2.51), (4, 6.85), (4, 10.14), (4, 8.86), (4, 9.45), (4, 8.37), (1, 3.73), (4, 8.33), (1, 3.51), (4, 7.74), (1, 3.65), (1, 2.89), (1, 4.44), (1, 1.46), (1, 3.2), (4, 8.78), (1, 3.46), (4, 8.55), (4, 7.92), (1, 3.53), (1, 3.4), (1, 3.05), (4, 9.84), (4, 10.72), (1, 2.35), (4, 9.04), (1, 2.49), (1, 3.17), (1, 2.92), (1, 1.54), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.55), (4, 6.87), (4, 8.1), (4, 8.3), (1, 1.59), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.74), (1, 3.38), (4, 9.26), (4, 9.49), (4, 9.17), (1, 1.7), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.34), (1, 3.79), (4, 7.61), (1, 1.24), (4, 9.3), (1, 1.46), (4, 7.14), (1, 3.88), (1, 3.71), (4, 8.5), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.8), (1, 2.43), (4, 7.84), (1, 1.72), (1, 3.72), (4, 7.78), (1, 1.34), (1, 1.85), (1, 2.15), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.25), (4, 8.06), (4, 9.28), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.85), (1, 1.91), (4, 8.31), (4, 8.69), (1, 1.93), (4, 8.26), (1, 1.96), (1, 3.09), (1, 2.7), (4, 9.07), (4, 9.12), (4, 9.62), (1, 3.98), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.31), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.07), (1, 4.01), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.04), (1, 1.73), (1, 1.21), (4, 8.66), (4, 10.87), (1, 4.13), (4, 8.75), (4, 7.61), (4, 7.44), (1, 1.05), (1, 2.81), (1, 3.27), (4, 9.52), (4, 8.67), (4, 8.93), (1, 1.05), (1, 3.36), (4, 9.08), (1, 2.8), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.65), (1, 3.09), (1, 3.25), (1, 3.11), (1, 2.6), (4, 8.99), (4, 8.02), (4, 8.84), (4, 8.22), (4, 8.71), (1, 2.23), (1, 2.25), (4, 8.67), (4, 9.06), (4, 6.9), (4, 8.85), (4, 8.29), (1, 3.07), (1, 4.18), (4, 7.63), (4, 8.88), (1, 2.33), (1, 1.84), (1, 2.95), (1, 3.26), (1, 2.61), (4, 6.2), (1, 3.41), (4, 9.61), (4, 8.38), (1, 2.34), (4, 10.3), (4, 6.93), (1, 2.64), (4, 8.97), (4, 7.21), (1, 3.13), (4, 7.7), (1, 2.5), (4, 9.13), (4, 8.45), (4, 8.35), (1, 3.14), (4, 6.59), (1, 2.99), (4, 6.6), (4, 7.69), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.44), (1, 2.79), (4, 6.7), (1, 3.35), (1, 3.39), (4, 7.57), (1, 3.34), (4, 9.68), (4, 7.94), (1, 1.92), (4, 9.16), (4, 8.67), (1, 1.05), (4, 9.6), (4, 8.21), (1, 3.15), (1, 1.58), (4, 9.36), (1, 2.01)]
```

I would like to end up with two vectors, `X` and `Y` (containing all first and all second values, respectively). I am stuck trying to remove the brackets and parentheses from this string.

I tried copying this string to MATLAB and use `textscan` to take off the curved brackets. However, I still couldn't remove the square brackets.

Comment: Please include text as text; not image. Please show us what you already have tried. Please [edit] your question to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `regexp` + `str2double`, i.e.,

```
[~, ~, ~, M] = regexp(s,'\d+(\.\d+)?');
m =str2double(M);
x = m(1:2:end);
y = m(2:2:end);
```

**DATA**

```
s = "[(1, 1.89), (1, 3.93), (4, 8.65), (4, 9.35), (1, 2.4), (1, 2.37), (1, 2.14), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.46), (4, 9.21), (4, 9.21), (1, 1.48), (1, 2.96), (4, 10.39), (1, 2.69), (1, 1.25), (1, 2.39), (1, 3.08), (1, 2.81), (1, 2.72), (1, 1.05), (1, 4.73), (1, 1.7), (1, 4.49), (1, 2.25), (1, 2.73), (1, 3.69), (1, 3.23), (4, 7.78), (1, 2.7), (4, 7.47), (1, 2.01), (4, 7.41), (1, 2.4), (1, 1.81), (1, 2.75), (4, 8.35), (4, 7.88), (1, 2.33), (4, 9.26), (1, 2.74), (1, 1.43), (1, 3.14), (1, 4.44), (1, 2.51), (4, 6.85), (4, 10.14), (4, 8.86), (4, 9.45), (4, 8.37), (1, 3.73), (4, 8.33), (1, 3.51), (4, 7.74), (1, 3.65), (1, 2.89), (1, 4.44), (1, 1.46), (1, 3.2), (4, 8.78), (1, 3.46), (4, 8.55), (4, 7.92), (1, 3.53), (1, 3.4), (1, 3.05), (4, 9.84), (4, 10.72), (1, 2.35), (4, 9.04), (1, 2.49), (1, 3.17), (1, 2.92), (1, 1.54), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.55), (4, 6.87), (4, 8.1), (4, 8.3), (1, 1.59), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.74), (1, 3.38), (4, 9.26), (4, 9.49), (4, 9.17), (1, 1.7), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.34), (1, 3.79), (4, 7.61), (1, 1.24), (4, 9.3), (1, 1.46), (4, 7.14), (1, 3.88), (1, 3.71), (4, 8.5), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.8), (1, 2.43), (4, 7.84), (1, 1.72), (1, 3.72), (4, 7.78), (1, 1.34), (1, 1.85), (1, 2.15), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.25), (4, 8.06), (4, 9.28), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.85), (1, 1.91), (4, 8.31), (4, 8.69), (1, 1.93), (4, 8.26), (1, 1.96), (1, 3.09), (1, 2.7), (4, 9.07), (4, 9.12), (4, 9.62), (1, 3.98), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.31), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.07), (1, 4.01), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.04), (1, 1.73), (1, 1.21), (4, 8.66), (4, 10.87), (1, 4.13), (4, 8.75), (4, 7.61), (4, 7.44), (1, 1.05), (1, 2.81), (1, 3.27), (4, 9.52), (4, 8.67), (4, 8.93), (1, 1.05), (1, 3.36), (4, 9.08), (1, 2.8), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.65), (1, 3.09), (1, 3.25), (1, 3.11), (1, 2.6), (4, 8.99), (4, 8.02), (4, 8.84), (4, 8.22), (4, 8.71), (1, 2.23), (1, 2.25), (4, 8.67), (4, 9.06), (4, 6.9), (4, 8.85), (4, 8.29), (1, 3.07), (1, 4.18), (4, 7.63), (4, 8.88), (1, 2.33), (1, 1.84), (1, 2.95), (1, 3.26), (1, 2.61), (4, 6.2), (1, 3.41), (4, 9.61), (4, 8.38), (1, 2.34), (4, 10.3), (4, 6.93), (1, 2.64), (4, 8.97), (4, 7.21), (1, 3.13), (4, 7.7), (1, 2.5), (4, 9.13), (4, 8.45), (4, 8.35), (1, 3.14), (4, 6.59), (1, 2.99), (4, 6.6), (4, 7.69), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.44), (1, 2.79), (4, 6.7), (1, 3.35), (1, 3.39), (4, 7.57), (1, 3.34), (4, 9.68), (4, 7.94), (1, 1.92), (4, 9.16), (4, 8.67), (1, 1.05), (4, 9.6), (4, 8.21), (1, 3.15), (1, 1.58), (4, 9.36), (1, 2.01)]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, you data is well-structured, so there are several things you could do:

```matlab
function vec = q60595838(s)
if ~nargin
  s = "[(1, 1.89), (1, 3.93), (4, 8.65), (4, 9.35), (1, 2.4), (1, 2.37), (1, 2.14), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.46), (4, 9.21), (4, 9.21), (1, 1.48), (1, 2.96), (4, 10.39), (1, 2.69), (1, 1.25), (1, 2.39), (1, 3.08), (1, 2.81), (1, 2.72), (1, 1.05), (1, 4.73), (1, 1.7), (1, 4.49), (1, 2.25), (1, 2.73), (1, 3.69), (1, 3.23), (4, 7.78), (1, 2.7), (4, 7.47), (1, 2.01), (4, 7.41), (1, 2.4), (1, 1.81), (1, 2.75), (4, 8.35), (4, 7.88), (1, 2.33), (4, 9.26), (1, 2.74), (1, 1.43), (1, 3.14), (1, 4.44), (1, 2.51), (4, 6.85), (4, 10.14), (4, 8.86), (4, 9.45), (4, 8.37), (1, 3.73), (4, 8.33), (1, 3.51), (4, 7.74), (1, 3.65), (1, 2.89), (1, 4.44), (1, 1.46), (1, 3.2), (4, 8.78), (1, 3.46), (4, 8.55), (4, 7.92), (1, 3.53), (1, 3.4), (1, 3.05), (4, 9.84), (4, 10.72), (1, 2.35), (4, 9.04), (1, 2.49), (1, 3.17), (1, 2.92), (1, 1.54), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.55), (4, 6.87), (4, 8.1), (4, 8.3), (1, 1.59), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.74), (1, 3.38), (4, 9.26), (4, 9.49), (4, 9.17), (1, 1.7), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.34), (1, 3.79), (4, 7.61), (1, 1.24), (4, 9.3), (1, 1.46), (4, 7.14), (1, 3.88), (1, 3.71), (4, 8.5), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.8), (1, 2.43), (4, 7.84), (1, 1.72), (1, 3.72), (4, 7.78), (1, 1.34), (1, 1.85), (1, 2.15), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.25), (4, 8.06), (4, 9.28), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.85), (1, 1.91), (4, 8.31), (4, 8.69), (1, 1.93), (4, 8.26), (1, 1.96), (1, 3.09), (1, 2.7), (4, 9.07), (4, 9.12), (4, 9.62), (1, 3.98), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.31), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.07), (1, 4.01), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.04), (1, 1.73), (1, 1.21), (4, 8.66), (4, 10.87), (1, 4.13), (4, 8.75), (4, 7.61), (4, 7.44), (1, 1.05), (1, 2.81), (1, 3.27), (4, 9.52), (4, 8.67), (4, 8.93), (1, 1.05), (1, 3.36), (4, 9.08), (1, 2.8), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.65), (1, 3.09), (1, 3.25), (1, 3.11), (1, 2.6), (4, 8.99), (4, 8.02), (4, 8.84), (4, 8.22), (4, 8.71), (1, 2.23), (1, 2.25), (4, 8.67), (4, 9.06), (4, 6.9), (4, 8.85), (4, 8.29), (1, 3.07), (1, 4.18), (4, 7.63), (4, 8.88), (1, 2.33), (1, 1.84), (1, 2.95), (1, 3.26), (1, 2.61), (4, 6.2), (1, 3.41), (4, 9.61), (4, 8.38), (1, 2.34), (4, 10.3), (4, 6.93), (1, 2.64), (4, 8.97), (4, 7.21), (1, 3.13), (4, 7.7), (1, 2.5), (4, 9.13), (4, 8.45), (4, 8.35), (1, 3.14), (4, 6.59), (1, 2.99), (4, 6.6), (4, 7.69), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.44), (1, 2.79), (4, 6.7), (1, 3.35), (1, 3.39), (4, 7.57), (1, 3.34), (4, 9.68), (4, 7.94), (1, 1.92), (4, 9.16), (4, 8.67), (1, 1.05), (4, 9.6), (4, 8.21), (1, 3.15), (1, 1.58), (4, 9.36), (1, 2.01)]";
end

%% Method 1:
s1 = strsplit(s, "), ");
s2 = erase(s1, ["[", "(", ")", "]", ","]);
vec = double(split(s2.', " "));

%% Method 2:
ast = py.importlib.import_module('ast');
mapper = @(item)[double(item{1}), double(item{2})];
vec = cell2mat(cellfun( mapper , cell(ast.literal_eval(s)), 'UniformOutput', false).');
```

Where the latter requires [Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-python.html) to be installed and recognized by MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way too if you wanna use textscan :

```
test_txt = ['(1, 1.89), (1, 3.93), (4, 8.65), (4, 9.35), (1, 2.4), (1, 2.37), (1, 2.14), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.46), (4, 9.21), (4, 9.21), (1, 1.48), (1, 2.96), (4, 10.39), (1, 2.69), (1, 1.25), (1, 2.39), (1, 3.08), (1, 2.81), (1, 2.72), (1, 1.05), (1, 4.73), (1, 1.7), (1, 4.49), (1, 2.25), (1, 2.73), (1, 3.69), (1, 3.23), (4, 7.78), (1, 2.7), (4, 7.47), (1, 2.01), (4, 7.41), (1, 2.4), (1, 1.81), (1, 2.75), (4, 8.35), (4, 7.88), (1, 2.33), (4, 9.26), (1, 2.74), (1, 1.43), (1, 3.14), (1, 4.44), (1, 2.51), (4, 6.85), (4, 10.14), (4, 8.86), (4, 9.45), (4, 8.37), (1, 3.73), (4, 8.33), (1, 3.51), (4, 7.74), (1, 3.65), (1, 2.89), (1, 4.44), (1, 1.46), (1, 3.2), (4, 8.78), (1, 3.46), (4, 8.55), (4, 7.92), (1, 3.53), (1, 3.4), (1, 3.05), (4, 9.84), (4, 10.72), (1, 2.35), (4, 9.04), (1, 2.49), (1, 3.17), (1, 2.92), (1, 1.54), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.55), (4, 6.87), (4, 8.1), (4, 8.3), (1, 1.59), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.74), (1, 3.38), (4, 9.26), (4, 9.49), (4, 9.17), (1, 1.7), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.34), (1, 3.79), (4, 7.61), (1, 1.24), (4, 9.3), (1, 1.46), (4, 7.14), (1, 3.88), (1, 3.71), (4, 8.5), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.8), (1, 2.43), (4, 7.84), (1, 1.72), (1, 3.72), (4, 7.78), (1, 1.34), (1, 1.85), (1, 2.15), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.25), (4, 8.06), (4, 9.28), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.85), (1, 1.91), (4, 8.31), (4, 8.69), (1, 1.93), (4, 8.26), (1, 1.96), (1, 3.09), (1, 2.7), (4, 9.07), (4, 9.12), (4, 9.62), (1, 3.98), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.31), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.07), (1, 4.01), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.04), (1, 1.73), (1, 1.21), (4, 8.66), (4, 10.87), (1, 4.13), (4, 8.75), (4, 7.61), (4, 7.44), (1, 1.05), (1, 2.81), (1, 3.27), (4, 9.52), (4, 8.67), (4, 8.93), (1, 1.05), (1, 3.36), (4, 9.08), (1, 2.8), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.65), (1, 3.09), (1, 3.25), (1, 3.11), (1, 2.6), (4, 8.99), (4, 8.02), (4, 8.84), (4, 8.22), (4, 8.71), (1, 2.23), (1, 2.25), (4, 8.67), (4, 9.06), (4, 6.9), (4, 8.85), (4, 8.29), (1, 3.07), (1, 4.18), (4, 7.63), (4, 8.88), (1, 2.33), (1, 1.84), (1, 2.95), (1, 3.26), (1, 2.61), (4, 6.2), (1, 3.41), (4, 9.61), (4, 8.38), (1, 2.34), (4, 10.3), (4, 6.93), (1, 2.64), (4, 8.97), (4, 7.21), (1, 3.13), (4, 7.7), (1, 2.5), (4, 9.13), (4, 8.45), (4, 8.35), (1, 3.14), (4, 6.59), (1, 2.99), (4, 6.6), (4, 7.69), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.44), (1, 2.79), (4, 6.7), (1, 3.35), (1, 3.39), (4, 7.57), (1, 3.34), (4, 9.68), (4, 7.94), (1, 1.92), (4, 9.16), (4, 8.67), (1, 1.05), (4, 9.6), (4, 8.21), (1, 3.15), (1, 1.58), (4, 9.36), (1, 2.01)'] ;
s = size(test_txt,2) ;
N = floor(s/9) ;
C = textscan(test_txt,'(%d,%.2f),',N) ;
x = C{1} ;
y = C{2} ;
```

I tried it, and I think it works as you wanted (i checked the first and last values of x and y pairs which are the same that in test_txt). The `N` is computed by dividing the size of the char vector `s` by the size of one bracket pair `(1, 1.11)` (which has 9 characters including the brackets and the space after the virgule) assuming.

**PS:** (Edit !!)

Watch out, the computation of `N` above this works only if the format of your pairs is the same for all the pairs ! But it not the case here (for example the fourth pairs is `(1, 2.4)` while the previous computation `s/9` would be consistent only if it was formatted as `(1, 2.40)`.

A better way to define `N` would be to count the opening bracket `(` like this :

```
index_bracket = find(test_txt(:)=='(') ;
N = size(index_bracket,1) ;
```

This should work (and sorry for the edit) !

Answer (score 1):

I think you can tweak Dev-iL's solution to make it simpler and faster

```
s1 = extractBetween(s, "(",")");
s1 = split(s1,", ",2);
vec = double(s1);
```

For kicks, I benchmarked our solutions. I wasn't getting the right answer from Kiwi GM's solution so I left it out.

```
Dev-iL's performance 3.93
ThomasIsCoding's performance 68.6
My performance 0.873

function profFunc

s = "[(1, 1.89), (1, 3.93), (4, 8.65), (4, 9.35), (1, 2.4), (1, 2.37), (1, 2.14), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.46), (4, 9.21), (4, 9.21), (1, 1.48), (1, 2.96), (4, 10.39), (1, 2.69), (1, 1.25), (1, 2.39), (1, 3.08), (1, 2.81), (1, 2.72), (1, 1.05), (1, 4.73), (1, 1.7), (1, 4.49), (1, 2.25), (1, 2.73), (1, 3.69), (1, 3.23), (4, 7.78), (1, 2.7), (4, 7.47), (1, 2.01), (4, 7.41), (1, 2.4), (1, 1.81), (1, 2.75), (4, 8.35), (4, 7.88), (1, 2.33), (4, 9.26), (1, 2.74), (1, 1.43), (1, 3.14), (1, 4.44), (1, 2.51), (4, 6.85), (4, 10.14), (4, 8.86), (4, 9.45), (4, 8.37), (1, 3.73), (4, 8.33), (1, 3.51), (4, 7.74), (1, 3.65), (1, 2.89), (1, 4.44), (1, 1.46), (1, 3.2), (4, 8.78), (1, 3.46), (4, 8.55), (4, 7.92), (1, 3.53), (1, 3.4), (1, 3.05), (4, 9.84), (4, 10.72), (1, 2.35), (4, 9.04), (1, 2.49), (1, 3.17), (1, 2.92), (1, 1.54), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.55), (4, 6.87), (4, 8.1), (4, 8.3), (1, 1.59), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.74), (1, 3.38), (4, 9.26), (4, 9.49), (4, 9.17), (1, 1.7), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.34), (1, 3.79), (4, 7.61), (1, 1.24), (4, 9.3), (1, 1.46), (4, 7.14), (1, 3.88), (1, 3.71), (4, 8.5), (1, 1.05), (4, 7.8), (1, 2.43), (4, 7.84), (1, 1.72), (1, 3.72), (4, 7.78), (1, 1.34), (1, 1.85), (1, 2.15), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.25), (4, 8.06), (4, 9.28), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.85), (1, 1.91), (4, 8.31), (4, 8.69), (1, 1.93), (4, 8.26), (1, 1.96), (1, 3.09), (1, 2.7), (4, 9.07), (4, 9.12), (4, 9.62), (1, 3.98), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.31), (1, 2.35), (4, 7.07), (1, 4.01), (1, 1.05), (4, 8.04), (1, 1.73), (1, 1.21), (4, 8.66), (4, 10.87), (1, 4.13), (4, 8.75), (4, 7.61), (4, 7.44), (1, 1.05), (1, 2.81), (1, 3.27), (4, 9.52), (4, 8.67), (4, 8.93), (1, 1.05), (1, 3.36), (4, 9.08), (1, 2.8), (4, 7.95), (4, 9.65), (1, 3.09), (1, 3.25), (1, 3.11), (1, 2.6), (4, 8.99), (4, 8.02), (4, 8.84), (4, 8.22), (4, 8.71), (1, 2.23), (1, 2.25), (4, 8.67), (4, 9.06), (4, 6.9), (4, 8.85), (4, 8.29), (1, 3.07), (1, 4.18), (4, 7.63), (4, 8.88), (1, 2.33), (1, 1.84), (1, 2.95), (1, 3.26), (1, 2.61), (4, 6.2), (1, 3.41), (4, 9.61), (4, 8.38), (1, 2.34), (4, 10.3), (4, 6.93), (1, 2.64), (4, 8.97), (4, 7.21), (1, 3.13), (4, 7.7), (1, 2.5), (4, 9.13), (4, 8.45), (4, 8.35), (1, 3.14), (4, 6.59), (1, 2.99), (4, 6.6), (4, 7.69), (1, 1.64), (4, 8.44), (1, 2.79), (4, 6.7), (1, 3.35), (1, 3.39), (4, 7.57), (1, 3.34), (4, 9.68), (4, 7.94), (1, 1.92), (4, 9.16), (4, 8.67), (1, 1.05), (4, 9.6), (4, 8.21), (1, 3.15), (1, 1.58), (4, 9.36), (1, 2.01)]";
n = 10000;

tic;
for i = 1:n
    s1 = strsplit(s, "), ");
    s2 = erase(s1, ["[", "(", ")", "]", ","]);
    vec = double(split(s2.', " "));
end
fprintf("Dev-iL's performance %.3g\n", toc);

tic;
for i = 1:n
    [~, ~, ~, M] = regexp(s,'\d+(\.\d+)?');
    m = str2double(M);
    x = m(1:2:end);
    y = m(2:2:end);
end
fprintf("ThomasIsCoding's performance %.3g\n", toc);

tic;
for i = 1:n
    s1 = extractBetween(s, "(",")");
    s1 = split(s1,", ",2);
    vec = double(s1);
end
fprintf("My performance %.3g\n", toc);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! It might be worth mentioning which MATLAB version is required to run this, since they're introducing new string-related functionality almost at every release. +1

Comment: Also, for reliable benchmarking one should use `timeit`.

Comment: timeit is useful for a quick test, but I'm not a big fan of it. It includes function handle overhead which may also affect how things execute, and, if your code is too fast it's not very precise. I like writing my own loops with tic-toc because it executes similarly to the way the code will be written (not going through a function handle). You can see that the timeit code just uses tic-toc.

Comment: @matlabbit: `timeit` factors in function handle overhead and the overhead of the loops, giving you just the time of the code itself. I think few people would be willing to put in the time needed to recreate the level of precision that `timeit` offers.